# String '2023-01-16 07:43:43 ص' was not recognized as a valid DateTime error

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, datetime, .net-core

We are trying to implement Arabic language support in our `dot net Core` application and facing some issues with `DateTime` conversions in our APIs where we are passing the dates like below..

[image]

But in the backend the dates are received as below when selected language is passed as Arabic in the `Header` of the `Request`.

[image]

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(appointmentDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

so wherever we are converting the string representation of dates to DateTime, we are getting exceptions.

`String '2023-01-16 07:43:43 ص' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

If we use `CurrentCulture`, then also application is breaking in few places as DateTime are not passed from UI in consistent way. Is there a way in Backend (dot net core middleware pipeline or somewhere) where we can configure to not convert the datetimes to Arabic format so that we can use the InvariantCulture?

We have configured the localization in the startup file as below.

[image]

How can we fix this issue and how can we have an easy fix of this as the dates are being used in almost entire application and seems like we will have to make a change in all the places to fix this?

Comment: No matter what's your language, `2023-01-16 07:43:43 s` is not a valid Datetime....

Comment: @Rena that's Arabic format..

Comment: Hi @WAQ, is your local machine's datetime Arabic format?

Comment: No.. selectedLanguage is a parameter passed in the header of each request from the application and its value can be en-US (English) or ar-AE (Arabic)

Answer (score -1):

You need to mention

CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("ar-AE");

Here is the complete working code

```
string dateString = "2023-01-16 07:43:43 ص";
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt"; // The format should match the input string

CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("ar-AE"); // Specify the Arabic (Saudi Arabia) culture

DateTime parsedDate;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.ToString());
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse the date.");
}
```